# How do I get a list of coordinates from a polygon?

Tags: enterprise-geodatabase, oracle-spatial, st-geometry

I have a table with polygon geometries and need to get a list of polygon vertices. Using `select sde.st_astext(geometry_column) from table_name;` I can get the WKT representation of the polygon but I'd prefer a list of x, y values as it's easier  to read.

This question is about getting the desired result from Oracle / SDE but for reference, in PostgreSQL / PostGIS I would likely use a combination of ST_DumpPoints and ST_X or ST_Y to create this list. However, I don't see how to perform the same task in Oracle / SDE.

How do I generate a list of X,Y values from a polygon geometry in Oracle / SDE?

Comment: If you use SDE this is not really Oracle but SDE question. Oracle has native functions only for its own SDO_GEOMETRY type.

Comment: I've been fighting with this myself for the past little while. I don't have time right now to post a full answer, but will do next week. As far as I can tell, there isn't an out-of-the-box way to do this. The best solution I've come up with is to either A) Convert the SDE.ST_GEOMETRY table to SDO.GEOMETRY. From there use Oracle Locator's GET VERTICES function (Oracle Locator is the free part of Oracle Spatial, included with every Oracle db). B) If converting isn't an option, maybe a copy of the SDE.ST_GEOMETRY as SDO_GEOMETRY would do (think: scheduled python task or materialized db view).

Comment: Some things I've been working on: 1) http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/154995/cross-join-on-a-numbers-table-to-get-line-vertices-is-there-a-better-way  2) http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/218241/get-xml-from-oracle-sde-st-geometry-shape-column-using-sql  3) http://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/156210/convert-user-defined-type-subclass-to-superclass  4) http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/218558/how-to-get-arcmap-to-recognize-st-point-sde-st-geometry  5) http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/209894/update-sde-st-geometry-m-values-to-cumulative-distance-using-sql

Comment: http://gis.stackexchange.com/questions/90927/how-to-get-x-y-coordinates-of-all-vertices-from-polygon-in-shapefile-as-excel-sp

Comment: Just a friendly heads up: [Spatial now free with all editions of Oracle Database](https://blogs.oracle.com/oraclespatial/spatial-now-free-with-all-editions-of-oracle-database)

Answer (score 1):

If you were to use WKT into QGIS with the QUICK WKT plugin, that would get you to formed polygon geometry, and then:

```
Vector -> Geometry tools -> Extract nodes
```

then:

```
Vector -> Geometry tools -> Extract Geometry column
```

This should get you to  with X and Y columns